# How to test if any value in a data frame is above limit

Tags: r

I have a data frame that follows this format

df1:

```
Value1 Value2 Value3 ...
0      0      4 
2      3      0
```

I have another data frame that looks like this

df2:

```
Name   Limit
Value1 3
Value2 2
Value3 3
...
```

I need to check for every value in df1 if it is above it's limit (which comes from df2).

I'm not sure how best to tackle this. The actual dfs are large and I can't figure out if I can loop through or do it in some other way.

Answer (score 2):

One approach - `Map` the values in `df2` to `df1` by `Name`/Column name, then compare. E.g.:

```
data.frame(Map(`>`, df1, df2$Limit[match(names(df1), df2$Name)]))
#  Value1 Value2 Value3
#1  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#2  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

I'm not certain what output you want - if you need to just know if `any` value is higher, then:

```
mapply(function(d,l) any(d > l), df1, df2$Limit[match(names(df1), df2$Name)])
#Value1 Value2 Value3 
# FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Example data used:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Value1 Value2 Value3
0      0      4 
2      3      0", header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text="Name   Limit
Value1 3
Value2 2
Value3 3", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
library(tibble)
df1 > deframe(df2)[col(df2)]
#     Value1 Value2 Value3
#[1,]  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#[2,]  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the names need not to be matched (they are sorted) you can use `sweep`.

```
sweep(df1, 2, df2$Limit, ">")
#     Value1 Value2 Value3
#[1,]  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#[2,]  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Or expand `df2$Limit` with `col`.

```
df1 > df2$Limit[col(df1)]
#     Value1 Value2 Value3
#[1,]  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
#[2,]  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

In case they need to be matched:

```
sweep(df1, 2, df2$Limit[match(names(df1), df2$Name)], ">")
df1 > df2$Limit[match(names(df1), df2$Name)][col(df1)]
```

In case you need an answer per column you can use `colSums`:

```
colSums(sweep(df1, 2, df2$Limit, ">")) > 0
#colSums(df1 > df2$Limit[col(df1)]) > 0
#Value1 Value2 Value3 
# FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: Hi this was very helpful. Say I have a column in df1 that is the ID for each row in df1. How can I use sweep without changing that column to TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: If it is e.g. the first column in `df1` than use `df1[-1]` to exclude the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a loop like this, saving the results in a list and then use `cbind` to concatenate the results:

```
#code
vecnames <- names(df1)
List <- list()
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(vecnames))
{
  List[[i]] <- df1[[vecnames[i]]] > df2$Limit[df2$Name==vecnames[i]]
  names(List)[i] <- vecnames[i]
}
#Bind
do.call(cbind,List)
```

Output:

```
     Value1 Value2 Value3
[1,]  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
[2,]  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1 <- structure(list(Value1 = c(0L, 2L), Value2 = c(0L, 3L), Value3 = c(4L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"), Limit = c(3L, 
2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get `df1` in long format, join with `df2` and for each `Name` check if any value exceeds `limit`. Using @thelatemail's data.

In base R, you can implement this logic with `stack`, `merge` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(values > Limit~Name, merge(df2, stack(df1), by.x = 'Name', by.y = 'ind'), any)
```

Or in `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'Name') %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'Name') %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value = any(value > Limit))

#  Name   Value
#  <chr>  <lgl>
#1 Value1 FALSE
#2 Value2 TRUE 
#3 Value3 TRUE
```